# Add multiple line in Row Widget

Tags: flutter, row

I have wrapped 3 Text in Row, but get exceptions. How can I make them displayed multiple line ?

```
 Row(children: [
     Text("this is text 1 bla bla bla"),
     Text("this is text 2 bla bla bla"),
     Text("this is text 3 bla bla bla"),
    ],),
```

**Error**

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 26 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Flexible` to solve this

```dart
      Row(children: [
        Flexible(child: Text("this is text 1 bla bla bla")),
        Flexible(child: Text("this is text 2 bla bla bla")),
        Flexible(child: Text("this is text 3 bla bla bla")),
      ])
```

Or you can use `Wrap` to show as a grid

```dart
      Wrap(children: [
        Text("this is text 1 bla bla bla"),
        Text("this is text 2 bla bla bla"),
        Text("this is text 3 bla bla bla"),
      ])
```